# How to map an object to all input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which load form data from an object to all input element.

```
function loadFormData(customerObj) {
    debugger

    $('#id').val(customerObj.id);
    $('#fullName').val(customerObj.fullName);
    $('#email').val(customerObj.email);
    $('#job').val(customerObj.job);
    $('#address').val(customerObj.address);
    $('#phone').val(customerObj.phone);

}
```

Since the object property match with input element id, is there a way to auto map it instead of manually populate it like above code?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
function loadFormData(customerObj) {

    $.each(customerObj, function(id,value){
    
        $( "#"+id ).val( value );
    
    });
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```js
function loadFormData(customerObj) {
  let fields = ['id', 'fullName', 'email'];

  fields.forEach((field) => {
    $(`#${field}`).val(customerObj[field])
  });
}
```